# Как убрать из строки подряд идущие повторы символа | - вертикальная черта

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sed

На входе строка:

```
"J3E||F3E|R3E|||H3E"
```

На на выходе без повторов символа "|":

```
"J3E|F3E|R3E|H3E"
```

В принципе вот так работает:

```
echo "J3E||F3E|R3E|||H3E" |   sed 's/[\|][\|]*/|/g'
```

Но, если я хочу заменить Только от трех и более подряд идущих символов "|||...", например так:

```
echo "J3E||F3E|R3E|||H3E" |   sed 's/[\|]{3,}/|/g'
```

Ничего не получается.
Как правильно  использовать квантификаторы "фигурные скобки" для данной задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте следующий шаблон POSIX BRE:

```bash
echo "J3E||F3E|R3E|||H3E" | sed 's/|\{3,\}/|/g'
```

Чтобы не нужно было экранировать фигурные скобки, используйте `-E` (POSIX ERE):

```bash
echo "J3E||F3E|R3E|||H3E" | sed -E 's/\|{3,}/|/g'
```

Заметьте, что в POSIX BRE символ `|` является обычным, а в POSIX ERE — специальным (поэтому во втором решении он экранирован).

Смотрите [пример работы кода онлайн](https://ideone.com/zkkkGr).

Comment: ссылка почему-то не открывается: https://ideone.com/zkkkGr

Comment: @kitworker Открывается отлично. [Вот ещё одна ссылка](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/X1lRPykzTz8JyOFKTc7IV1DyMnatqXEDEkEgRo2HsauSQo1CcWqKgnqxfk1MtbFOTK1@jX66OkH1uq4gLTE1QC0QHf//AwA)

Comment: @kitworker, ideone.com не доступен из РФ. Используйте VPN или Tor или ...

Answer (score -1):

Замена от 2 символов и больше

```
import re
result = re.sub(r"\|{2,}", '|', 'J3E||F3E|R3E|||H3E')
print(result)
```